# R - case_when() creating a new variable based on conditions of multiple existing variables

Tags: r, if-statement, variables, case

I am struggling to create a new variable named "edu_category" to indicate whether each person experiences Female Hypergamy (wive's education level < husband's), Female Homogamy (wive's education level == husband's), or Female Hypogamy (wive's education level > husband's).

My data looks like this (Female == 1 indicates this person is female, 0 indicates male):

| PersonID | Female | EducationLevel | SpouseID | SpouseEducation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 3 | 102 | 4 |
| 102 | 0 | 4 | 101 | 3 |
| 103 | 1 | 2 | 104 | 2 |
| 104 | 0 | 2 | 103 | 2 |
| 105 | 0 | 5 | 106 | 6 |
| 106 | 1 | 6 | 105 | 5 |

I wish to create a new variable so that my data looks like this:

| PersonID | Female | EducationLevel | SpouseID | SpouseEducation | edu_category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 3 | 102 | 4 | FHypergamy |
| 102 | 0 | 4 | 101 | 3 | FHypergamy |
| 103 | 1 | 2 | 104 | 2 | FHomogamy |
| 104 | 0 | 2 | 103 | 2 | FHomogamy |
| 105 | 0 | 5 | 106 | 6 | FHypogamy |
| 106 | 1 | 6 | 105 | 5 | FHypogamy |

Here, let's look at person with ID "105", his (because female == 0) education level is 5, his spouse's (person 106's) education level is 6, so it's Female Hypogamy, wive's education > husband's (we assume by default everyone's spouse is of opposite sex).

Now let's look at person with ID "106", since she is person 105's spouse, we also fill the variable "edu_category" with the same "FHypogamy". So essentially, we are looking at every unit of couples.

What I tried:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(edu_category = case_when((SpouseEducation > EducationLevel) | (Female == 1) ~ 'FemaleHypergamy',
                                   (SpouseEducation == EducationLevel) | (Female == 1) ~ 'FemaleHomogamy',
                                   (SpouseEducation < EducationLevel) | (Female == 1) ~ 'FemaleHypogamy',
                                   (SpouseEducation > EducationLevel) | (Female == 0) ~ 'FemaleHypogamy',
                                   (SpouseEducation == EducationLevel) | (Female == 0) ~ 'FemaleHomogamy',
                                   (SpouseEducation < EducationLevel) | (Female == 0) ~ 'FemaleHypergamy'))
```

However, it's not giving my accurate results - the variable "edu_category" itself is successfully created, but the "FemaleHypergamy", "FemaleHomogamy", and "FemaleHypogamy" are not reflecting accurate situations.

What should I do? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Should not it be `&` sign instead of `|` in those conditions?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be using the conditions and then `fill` the created NA's:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(edu_category = case_when(Female == 0 & EducationLevel < SpouseEducation ~ "FHypogamy",
                                  Female == 0 & EducationLevel == SpouseEducation ~ "Homogamy",
                                  Female == 0 & EducationLevel > SpouseEducation ~ "Hypergamy", 
                                  TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(edu_category, .direction = "updown")
```

```
  PersonID Female EducationLevel SpouseID SpouseEducation edu_category
1      101      1              3      102               4    Hypergamy
2      102      0              4      101               3    Hypergamy
3      103      1              2      104               2     Homogamy
4      104      0              2      103               2     Homogamy
5      105      0              5      106               6    FHypogamy
6      106      1              6      105               5    FHypogamy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(edu_category = case_when(
    (SpouseEducation > EducationLevel & Female == 1) ~ 'FemaleHypergamy',
    (SpouseEducation > EducationLevel & Female == 0) ~ 'FemaleHypogamy',
    (SpouseEducation < EducationLevel & Female == 1) ~ 'FemaleHypogamy',
    (SpouseEducation < EducationLevel & Female == 0) ~ 'FemaleHypergamy',
  SpouseEducation == EducationLevel  ~ 'FemaleHomogamy'))
```